# Share sessionStorage between 2 angular SPAs on localhost on different ports

Tags: javascript, angular, localhost, local-storage, session-storage

I have 2 angular applications (angular 7 and angular 1.5) running on 
different ports in dev mode. They are loaded one after another. User starts in first application (let's say localhost:3000) and at some point user is redirected to the second app (let's say localhost:8080).
I want them to share a session storage.
Is it possible in any way?

Comment: just thinking, can you pass sessionStorage in query string/request header to the second app, if possible?

Comment: No, it's too big

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Local_and_session_storage): Web storage offers two different storage areas—local storage and session storage—which differ in scope and lifetime. Data placed in local storage is per origin (the combination of protocol, hostname, and port number as defined in the same-origin policy) (the data is available to all scripts loaded from pages from the same origin that previously stored the data) and persists after the browser is closed. **Session storage is per-origin-per-window-or-tab** and is limited to the lifetime of the window. Session storage is intended to allow separate instances of the same web application to run in different windows without interfering with each other, a use case that's not well supported by cookies.[9]

This means that session storage, by design, will not allow you to access data outside of the window that created it. Even local storage, I believe, will prevent you from accessing data from a different port.

You could use something like IndexedDB to get and set data to a common data store from multiple different applications running in different tabs on different ports on the same machine.

For Angular 7, Cyrille Tuzi's [Angular Async Local Storage](https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage) library is very well developed and supported, and likely will enable you to do what you need. You may be able to find a similar library for Angular 1.x that will allow you to exchanged data via the same IndexedDb datastore.

Comment: angular-async-local-storage does not work here, i have two apps running on localhost but cannot read from the other app.

Comment: Are they running on the same port? Two instance of the same app, or two different apps? If they are different apps on different ports, then won’t be able to access each other’s data.

Comment: Different apps running on different ports.

Comment: Browser storage by design silos data so that an app on another port can’t access it, that’s a security feature. You would have to ask Cyrille specifically if there’s a way to work around that with his library.